# Get feature style properties - openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I have some geometric shape features loaded and I would like to change one style property only and keep the others with the values they have. Later I need to restore the original feature style.
I realize that feature.getSyle().getFill().getColor() is not the answer.
Is there any way to read individual feature style properies like Fill color and Stroke?
Thanks

Comment: The clone method, for example `var savedStyle = feature.getStyle().clone();` will take a copy which won't be affected by other changes you make

Comment: The clone method works but how can I read a single style property so that I can change only the Fill color, for example, and keep the Stroke and Text as it is in the original style?

Comment: Use getStyle + getStroke/Fill + get/setColor: feature.getStyle().getFill().setColor('red')